# GNU/Linux - proper use of the 'zip' command to flatten the subdirectories?

Tags: bash, directory, zip, subdirectory, directory-structure

I'm looking for some help in properly using the `zip` command in GNU/Linux systems. Let's say I have this directory structure (the actual use case is more complex, but this is a simplified example):

```
Documents
└── foo1
    └── foo2
        ├── foo3a 
        │   └──foo4
        │      ├──file1.txt
        │      └──file2.py
        └── foo3b
            └──foo4
               ├──file3.txt
               └──file4.py
```

I want to make a zip file that only includes the `txt` files. And ideally I want it to be part of a bash script running from the `Documents` location. So, referencing the [documentation of the zip function](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zip) I naively start with:

```
cd ~/Documents
zip -r foo . -i foo1/foo2/*/foo4/*.txt
```

This does zip up all the `txt` files, but the resulting `foo.zip` file has the full directory structure (foo1 -> foo2 -> foo3a/foo3b, etc...).

[image: zip folder structure]

I'd like to "flatten" it so that the `foo.zip` structure starts at foo2, even though the command is being run in `~/Documents`. The examples in the documentation all use the `.` as the `inpath` variable. So I try changing it to where I want `foo.zip` to start:

```
zip -r foo ./foo1/foo2 -i foo1/foo2/*/foo4/*.txt
```

But `foo.zip` still has the full directory path of foo1 -> foo2, etc... Even if I run

```
zip -r foo ./foo1/foo2/foo3a -i foo1/foo2/*/foo4/*.txt
```

It will only zip up `file1.txt` from `foo3a`, but the full directory structure remains. So the `inpath` variable only determines where the search for files starts from, not where the eventual zip directory starts from. I've tried other various versions of the zip command but I can't get the outcome I'm looking for. Is there any way of using the `zip` command to result in a `foo.zip` of:

```
foo.zip
├── foo3a 
│   └──foo4
│      ├──file1.txt
│      └──file2.py
└── foo3b
    └──foo4
       ├──file3.txt
       └──file4.py
```

Or even possibly flattening the downstream folders (since `foo4` is common to both) to something like:

```
foo.zip
├── foo3a 
│   └──file1.txt
│   └──file2.py
└── foo3b
    └──file3.txt
    └──file4.py
```

How would one do this? I also tried using the `-j` option:

```
zip -rj foo . -i foo1/foo2/*/foo4/*.txt
>> zip warning: zip file empty
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
cd ~/Documents
(cd foo1/foo2; zip -r - . -i '*.txt') >foo.zip
```

- `(...)` creates a subshell where a `cd` won't affect the top-level shell.
- Specifying an archive path of `-` causes the archive to be written to standard output.
- The `>foo.zip` causes the archive date to be written to the file `foo.zip` in the current directory for the top-level shell (`~/Documents`).

Answer (score 0):

```
zip -r --include '*.txt' -j foo.zip .
```

The -r traverses the whole tree.

The --include restricts the selection to txt files.

The -j stores the files only under their name, with no path information.

Comment: This does completely flatten everything in the zip folder to just the files. I didn't know you could reorder the arguments so that the archive name comes at the end. Interesting to know, although I still don't intuitively understand it. Thanks.

Comment: @Eric : I know, and I thought that this is what you wanted to achieve. I now re-read your post and see that you *do* want to keep a certain structure. However, according to your example, it is not clear to me what effect you would like to achieve when you have for instance two `foo4` directories on **different** levels of your tree, and not in parallel, as in your example. Perhaps you can, in addition to your example, give a precise description, under which condition a directory should be omitted from the zip file.